# In laravel SPA, I use the DataTables , when I use laravel's vue component，vue also require jquery, so the DataTables can't be load correctly

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, vuejs2

**In laravel SPA, When I use the DataTables which depends on jQuery,  when I use laravel's vue component，vue also require jquery, so the DataTables can't be load correctly， because  loading jquery twice. what should I do?**

**index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>控制台 | {{ config('webbackend.title') }}</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- ...some css... -->

        <!-- Datatables -->
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-scroller-bs/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
        <link href="/assets/admin/gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body class="nav-md">

        <div id="app"></div>

        <!-- load jQuery first-->
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- here is some plugins, they maybe dependent on jquery,so I can't delete previous line -->
        <!-- FastClick -->
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
        <!-- NProgress -->
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>


        <!-- Datatables -->
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

        <!-- main.js loaded jQuery already -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

        <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
        {{--<script src="/assets/admin/gentelella/build/js/custom.min.js"></script>--}}

    </body>
    </html>
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Comment: Define jQuery as component in mix: https://github.com/niiknow/anx-api-proxy/blob/master/webpack.mix.js#L11

Answer (score 0):

Verify if jQuery is loaded before VueJs.

Can pass some snippet of main.js? Please.